# Fastlane disable availability on Mac

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I am trying to disable the availability of my apps on Mac when I deploy them with Fastlane.
I found this article [enter link description here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/16973) but I do not understand how to implement this.

I've got a lane that is responsible for creating a new app. So I don't use Spaceship at all here. How can implement this on my end?

Thank you

Here is a part of the Fastfile code:

```
conf = get_app_config(app)
      update_user_credentials(conf)

      name = conf.company_name
      ios_meta = IosMetadata.new(conf)
      ios_meta.deploy

      puts "Screenshots: ##{ios_meta.screenshots_path}"

      deliver(
        force: true,
        username: ENV["USERNAME"],
        skip_binary_upload: false,
        ipa: File.join(path_to_ipa),
        app_icon: ios_meta.icon_path,
        app_version: options[:app_version],
        app_identifier: conf.app_identifier,
        screenshots_path: ios_meta.screenshots_path,
        overwrite_screenshots: true,
        metadata_path: ios_meta.metadata_path,
        ignore_language_directory_validation: true,
        submit_for_review: true,
        automatic_release: true,
        submission_information: {
          add_id_info_uses_idfa: true,
          add_id_info_limits_tracking: true,
          add_id_info_tracks_install: true,
          add_id_info_serves_ads: false,

          export_compliance_uses_encryption: false,
          export_compliance_encryption_updated: false,
          export_compliance_compliance_required: true,

          content_rights_contains_third_party_content: false,
          content_rights_has_rights: false
        },
        team_name: conf.team_name,
        team_id: conf.itc_team_id
      )
```

Any implementation of `is_opted_in_to_distribute_ios_app_on_mac_app_store` I tried inside this code brought errors of type "Unknown property"